I want to write a program with the help of a for loop, but I ran into a problem
I need a help
I am writing a program and I want it to show the largest number when I give it a set of numbers
I did it up to a point, but it seems that there is a mistake again
numbers=[12,4,3,4,27,89]

largest=None

for num in numbers :
    if largest is None or num > largest :
      print(largest)


What is the error message? I'm sure I know, but you should always include that information with your question on Stack Overflow.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk In this case, there likely is no error message, just unexpected and/or incorrect output.

@chepner: Good point, short-circuiting operators.

Use the builtin max function: print(max(numbers))

You never update the value of largest, so every value appears to be the largest.  After the loop is complete, and you've looked at every value of num, you print the final value of largest.
numbers = [12,4,3,4,27,89]

largest = None

for num in numbers :
    if largest is None or num > largest :
      largest = num

print(largest)


Personally, I dislike the need to repeatedly check largest is None when it is guaranteed that largest will be set to an actual number on the first iteration. I prefer a solution that initializes largest to a feasible value immediately.
numbers = [...]

itr = iter(numbers)

# largest is set to None only if numbers is empty;
# otherwise, it's set to numbers[0]
largest = next(itr, None)

for num in itr:
    # We only enter the loop if numbers started with
    # at least two values, so largest here is guaranteed
    # to be an element of numbers
    if num > largest:
        largest = num

print(largest)


Here is my implementation.
numbers = [12, 4, 3, 4, 27, 89]

# Initialize 'largest' with the first element of list
largest = numbers[0]

# Iterate through the list starting from the second element
for num in numbers[1:]:
    if num > largest:
        largest = num

print(largest)

